# Scroll down then fixed navigation glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

I have this glitch that is bothering me. The problem is that my navigation is not working properly as I wanted it to be. It jumps even though I have not reached the top of my nav or after passing the height of my header with scrollTop value. I recreate the problem in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/810gcqsg/).

```
var header_height = $('header').height();
//var main_nav = $('nav');
$(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= header_height) {
        $('nav').addClass("fixed");
    } else {
        $('nav').removeClass("fixed");
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of taking the height of header, you should be taking the top of `.main_nav` to compare with ScrollTop.
Change the first line in the code you posted above to:

```
var header_height = $('.main_nav').position().top;
```

That should work. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vpxkaueb/) is the working fiddle.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Your solution using position works! Mine is kinda the same but I use offset top instead of position. [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNmqLa). Thanks!